# Command is getting hanged on execution via fabric

Tags: python, fabric

When i am running the below command on one of the remote machine via fabric it is getting hanged.

```
def execute_lmo_scripts():
    print "preparing to execute lmo scripts................"    
    output = run("sudo suwww ; ")  # or this command  sudo("suwww",shell=False)
```

If i manually run the command on the remote server it is being executed probably.
Can any one please guide me on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Probably that you're using `run("sudo ..")` and not `sudo()` and the `sudo` command is asking for input that isn't being received, so it's waiting, forever.